# How to determine if a worksheet Cell is Visible/Displayed in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find if a cell is visible on the screen.

By visible, I don't mean hidden. I am specifically trying to find if a cell is currently displayed in the active sheet, or if it is not displayed, ie: it has been scrolled off of the visible active sheet.

I have looked online, and can only find the following code which doesn't seem to work for me:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Worksheets(1).Cells(10, 10)
        'MsgBox "Value: " & .Value & ", Top: " & .Top & ", Left: " & .Left
        Dim visibleCells As Range
        Set visibleCells = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Intersect(Worksheets(1).Cells(10, 10), visibleCells) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "This cell is not visible."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Marwan

Comment: Just Curious... What if say Cell A4 is hidden and you can see up till say rows 41. Would you consider cell A4 visible or hidden? Also What would you say for cells which are partially visible?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I would consider cell A4 as being visible. Some background on what I'm trying to accomplish, I need to find the LEFT and TOP of a particular cell. So I need to iterate through the cells to it's left and through the cells above it. I need to check if those cells are visible, and if they are, I need to sum their width (or height). The problem that I'm running into right now, is that some of the cells are frozen, and do not show up as part of the visible range. I'm not sure how to deal with that. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I figured out how to check if the cell is "frozen" or not, by using the following code:
`Function CellIsInFrozenRange(cell As Range)`
`Dim inRow As Boolean`
`Dim inColumn As Boolean`
`If (ActiveWindow.SplitRow > 0) Then`
`inRow = Not Intersect(cell, Range(Cells(1, 1),`
`Cells(ActiveWindow.SplitRow, 1).End(xlEnd))) Is Nothing`
`End If`
`If (ActiveWindow.SplitColumn > 0) Then`
`inColumn = Not Intersect(cell, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, ActiveWindow.SplitColumn).End(xlDown))) Is Nothing`
`End If`
`CellIsInFrozenRange = (inRow Or inColumn)`
`End Function`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a function that does what you want:

```
Function CellIsInVisibleRange(cell As Range)
CellIsInVisibleRange = Not Intersect(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange, cell) Is Nothing
End Function
```

At least I think it does.  I hadn't been aware of the VisibleRange property until now.

Call it like:

```
If CellIsInVisibleRange(ActiveSheet.Range("A35")) Then
    MsgBox "Cell is visible"
Else
    MsgBox "Cell isn't visible"
End If
```

Comment: + 1 I use this and one other variation to check for cell visibility.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - What is the other variation that you use?

Comment: @Marwan: It depends on your answer to my comment in your question :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout would you mind sharing the other variation you use to check for cell visibility?

Answer (score 3):

The function from @DougGlancy will work in most instances but it fails if the Range has a row height or column width set to zero.  This function adds logic to deal with that plus some error handling.

```
Function Range_IsVisibleInWindow(ByVal target As Excel.Range) As Boolean
' Returns TRUE if any cell in TARGET (Range) is visible in the Excel window.
'
'   Visible means (1) not hidden, (2) does not have row height or column width of
'   zero, (3) the view is scrolled so that the Range can be seen by the user at
'   that moment.
'
'   A partially visible cell will also return TRUE.

    If target Is Nothing Then
        ' Parameter is invalid.  Raise error.
        Err.Raise 3672, _
                  "Range_IsVisibleInWindow()", _
                  "Invalid parameter in procedure 'Range_IsVisible'."

    Else
        ' Parameter is valid.  Check if the Range is visible.
        Dim visibleWinLarge As Excel.Range
        Dim visibleWinActual As Excel.Range

        On Error Resume Next
        Set visibleWinLarge = Excel.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange ' active window range -INCLUDING- areas with zero column width/height
        Set visibleWinActual = visibleWinLarge.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' active window range -EXCLUDING- areas with zero column width/height
        Range_IsVisibleInWindow = Not Intersect(target, visibleWinActual) Is Nothing ' returns TRUE if at least one cell in TARGET is currently visible on screen
        On Error GoTo 0

    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I used this for filtered rows and worked perfectly