# How do I add a blank subtotal row after each different value in a specific column in data that has been filtered with an advanced filter?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, row, addition

I am getting an Excel 2010 Workbook with chunks of data.  There are a variable number of blank rows between each chunk of data.  Here's what I do with the data using macros:

1. I copy the data from the source workbook into a workbook with my macros.
2. I remove the blank rows.
3. I then sort the data with 4 sort criteria.
4. I then use an advanced filter to extract 6 of the 26 different types of data.
5. I then use the VBA code within a macro found here:  [How to automatically insert a blank row after a group of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417544/how-to-automatically-insert-a-blank-row-after-a-group-of-data/15418263#15418263) to add a blank row after each unique value in Column A, but I am getting numerous blank rows as it appears to be adding a blank rows based on the original data, not the filtered data:

What I need is a way to add a blank row after each unique value in column A after the data is filtered to add sub-totals and counts.

Comment: You need to post your current code, a data sample and an expected result.

Comment: This likely involves having to check if the cell is visible.  If you are working on a Range object, you can filter it down with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.  If you are just using single cells or something else, this link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943200/how-to-determine-if-a-worksheet-cell-is-visible-displayed-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

You might copy the filtered data to a separate spreadsheet tab then do the insert.
Otherwise you will have to use the SpecialCells property mentioned above, which is much more complex.