# Autofit Zoom View to active/visible cells in table?

Tags: excel, vba

I wasn't able to find any vba zoom except for auto-changing based on resolution, but is it possible to autofit custom zoom level based on most furthest out column that has text?

```
 Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100  'also you can change to other size
End Sub
```

Bonus Code:

To reset the scroll bar to far left, so it's looking at Column A/Row1, this code works :) I have it on a "reset" userbutton.

```
'Scroll to a specific row and column
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try the following: `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column).Select`

Comment: Zooms in way way close, thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Function FindFurthestColumn(S As Worksheet) As Integer
    
    Dim CellsWithContent As Long
    CellsWithContent = WorksheetFunction.CountA(S.Cells)
    
    If CellsWithContent = 0 Then
        FindFurthestColumn = 1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim CellsCount As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Do
        j = j + 1
        CellsCount = CellsCount + WorksheetFunction.CountA(S.Columns(j))
    Loop Until CellsCount = CellsWithContent
    
    FindFurthestColumn = j
End Function

Function CellIsVisible(cell As Range) As Boolean
    CellIsVisible = Not Intersect(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange, cell) Is Nothing
End Function

Sub ZoomVisibleCells()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    LastColumn = FindFurthestColumn(ActiveSheet)
    
    Dim SplitCell As Range
    If ActiveWindow.Split = True Then
        Set SplitCell = Cells(ActiveWindow.SplitRow + 1, ActiveWindow.SplitColumn + 1)
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    End If
    
    Dim Zoom As Integer
    For Zoom = 400 To 10 Step -1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = Zoom
        If CellIsVisible(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, LastColumn + 1)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Zoom
    
    If Not SplitCell Is Nothing Then
        SplitCell.Activate
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Credit for the CellIsVisible function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943260/14370454

Comment: https://imgur.com/izm9cLa, this made me a chuckle a bit but I think it's a great start :) thanks for your response

Comment: I see, the problem was caused by the Freeze Pane, here is the code again with the necessary fix:

Answer (score 0):

AUTO ZOOM RESPONSIVE VIEW EXCEL VBA CODE

In a sheet type any character on cell A1 and your last column view then type a character on first row with last column. That's it, see a magic of responsive view Excel sheet/s.

**Note:** copy this code and paste it to Thisworkbook module.

Thank you all.

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window) 
   Dim LastCol As Long 
   Dim rng As Range 
   Dim x As Integer 
   Dim y As Integer 
    With ActiveSheet 
               Set rng = .Rows(1).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
  End With 
If Not rng Is Nothing Then 
     LastCol = rng.Column 
Else 
     LastCol = 1 
End If 
x = 1 ' For First Column 
y = LastCol ' For Last 
     Columns(Chr(64 + x) & ":" & Chr(64 + y)).Select 
         ActiveWindow.Zoom = True 
         ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Select 
End Sub
```