# Using CountIfs in VBA with filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I filtered out some of my data using the `Autofilter` function. As a result, the filtered data consists of a non-contiguous range of cells.

Consequently, for example, when I use the `CountIfs` function to count the number of ****03-In Analysis**** from *Column C* that belong to **07-customer noticed** from *column A*, the `CountIfs` function counts the unfiltered data.

Filtered Data
[image: Filtered Data]

When I use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, I get an error due to the non-contiguous range of cells.

```vb
Dim sh, ws As Worksheet
Dim count
Dim range1, range2 As Range

Set range1 = ws.Range("A2:A297")
Set range2 = ws.Range("C2:C297")

count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(range1, "07-customer noticed", range2, "03-In Analysis")
sh.Range("A1") = count
```

Comment: why not apply your conditions as filters to the corresponding fields and count the number of visible rows?

Comment: @АлексейР Thank you for your advise! I was so focused on finding a solution using the```CountIfs```  method that I completely neglected on trying to implement simpler alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays work faster for me than worksheet functions.

I tried and tested the code below and it works for me.

```vb
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub Test()
    
    Dim sRange$
    Dim count&, iLastUsedRow&, iRow&
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B")
    
    With ws
        'last used row of data on this sheet
        iLastUsedRow = .Range("A" & Rows.count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'cells containing data
        sRange = "A2:C" & iLastUsedRow
        'transferring data to array
        aData = .Range(sRange)
    End With
    
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(aData)
        If Range_IsVisibleInWindow(ws.Range("A" & iRow + 1)) Then
            If aData(iRow, 1) = "07-customer noticed" And aData(iRow, 3) = "03-In Analysis" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
        
    End Sub
```

I copied this function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943200/how-to-determine-if-a-worksheet-cell-is-visible-displayed-in-vba) and upvoted their answer. You may want to thank them too in this way, if this works for you?

```vb
    Function Range_IsVisibleInWindow(ByVal target As Excel.Range) As Boolean
    ' Returns TRUE if any cell in TARGET (Range) is visible in the Excel window.
    '
    '   Visible means (1) not hidden, (2) does not have row height or column width of
    '   zero, (3) the view is scrolled so that the Range can be seen by the user at
    '   that moment.
    '
    '   A partially visible cell will also return TRUE.
    
        If target Is Nothing Then
            ' Parameter is invalid.  Raise error.
            Err.Raise 3672, _
                      "Range_IsVisibleInWindow()", _
                      "Invalid parameter in procedure 'Range_IsVisible'."
    
        Else
            ' Parameter is valid.  Check if the Range is visible.
            Dim visibleWinLarge As Excel.Range
            Dim visibleWinActual As Excel.Range
    
            On Error Resume Next
            Set visibleWinLarge = Excel.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange ' active window range -INCLUDING- areas with zero column width/height
            Set visibleWinActual = visibleWinLarge.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' active window range -EXCLUDING- areas with zero column width/height
            Range_IsVisibleInWindow = Not Intersect(target, visibleWinActual) Is Nothing ' returns TRUE if at least one cell in TARGET is currently visible on screen
            On Error GoTo 0
    
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, thank you for proposing your solution using arrays! I tried implementing your code. However, I noticed that your code still counts the unfiltered data too.

Comment: @A.Rodrigues Thanks for getting back to me. Apologies for my mistake. I have added this to my answer above. I have tested it and it works correctly.