# Select each of 'filtered' values in a column of Sheet 1 and find their occurences in all values of a column in Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba, comparison, excel-tables, listobject

I have an Excel worksheet comprised of two sheets.

One (Sheet 1) with a list of products, their respective serial numbers and a part number for a specific part - the users enters one or more serial numbers to filter the complete big list to end up with a smaller list of items

One seperate sheet (Sheet 2) that has only one column, a list of part numbers that need to be replaced

Now I want to write a VBA script that on Worksheet_Calculate() (not reflected below) compares the filtered values of a specific column in Sheet 1 (the column containing the part numbers) with the list/column in Sheet 2 and shows a message box for each product containing a part with a number found in the list of sheet2

But I'm having trouble finding a solution for collecting all filtered cells in Sheet 1

I assume I have to somehow make use of the ListObjects property to collect the specific visible/filtered cells and to compare only those to the list in sheet 2

But I don't really know how to select those specific, auto-filtered, cells or write an iteration that accounts for only those cells but still compares to all rows in the list/column of sheet 2

Right now, despite making use of col1 and col2 as ranges with the 'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)' attribute it always selects all cells of col1

I'm surprised that this selector

```
prod1 = Cells(r, col1.Column).Value
```

despite using col1 (which is a limited range) iterates all values, not just the filtered ones

```
Sub CompareTwoColumns()
    Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range, prod1 As String, lr As Long
    Dim incol1 As Variant, incol2 As Variant, r As Long
 
    Set col1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").ListColumns.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set col2 = Worksheets("Tabel2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    lr = Worksheets("Tabel1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    Dim cell As Range
               
    For r = 2 To lr
        prod1 = Cells(r, col1.Column).Value
   
        If prod1 <> "" Then
            Set incol2 = col2.Find(prod1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            If incol2 Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox CStr(prod1) + " Not in List"
            Else
                MsgBox CStr(prod1) + " Is in List!"
            End If
        End If
   
    Next r
End Sub
```

Anyone able to nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: The second answer on this page should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943200/how-to-determine-if-a-worksheet-cell-is-visible-displayed-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

### Match Value in Range

- Adjust the worksheet, table, and column names.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ComparePartNumbers()

    ' Often you loop through the cells of the destination worksheet
    ' and try to find a match in the source worksheet (read, copy from)
    ' and then in another column of the destination worksheet you write
    ' e.g. Yes or No (write, copy to).
    ' The analogy doesn't quite apply in this case but I used it anyway.
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim sTbl As ListObject: Set sTbl = sws.ListObjects("Table2")
    Dim sLc As ListColumn: Set sLc = sTbl.ListColumns("Part Number")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sLc.DataBodyRange
    
    ' Attempt to reference the destination range ('drg').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dTbl As ListObject: Set dTbl = dws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim dLc As ListColumn: Set dLc = dTbl.ListColumns("Part Number")
    Dim drg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set drg = dLc.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Validate the destination range.
    If drg Is Nothing Then ' no visible cells
        MsgBox "No filtered values.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    'Else ' there are visible cells; do nothing i.e. continue
    End If
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim dCell As Range ' current destination cell
    Dim dPartNumber As String ' current part number read from the cell
    Dim sIndex As Variant ' the n-th cell where the value was found or an error
    
    ' Loop.
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        dPartNumber = CStr(dCell.Value)
        If Len(dPartNumber) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            sIndex = Application.Match(dPartNumber, srg, 0)
            If IsNumeric(sIndex) Then ' is a match
                'MsgBox "'" & dPartNumber & "' is in list!", vbInformation
                Debug.Print "'" & dPartNumber & "' is in list!"
            Else ' is not a match (VBA: 'Error 2042' = Excel: '#N/A')
                'MsgBox "'" & dPartNumber & "' is not in list!", vbExclamation
                Debug.Print "'" & dPartNumber & "' is not in list!"
            End If
        'Else ' is blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next dCell

End Sub
```

Comment: That actually works perfectly, thank you!

Btw. I had to change dPartNumber to a Variant and remove the CStr from dCell.Value for pure numbers to work as well